# Getting an ordered ics file from google Calendar

Tags: php, events, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I hope you could help me.

I'm doing a little website for my friends and me, and there you have a private section where you can enter your calendar adress, and you get the next 5 events.

So I'm just using the ics file of the calendar, which is requested everytime you open the calendar (via the private ics adress)

But i don't get an orderd list of the next events, i'm also retrieving events in the past:
for example, the first 5 events which show up are this one:

- 20140704T163000Z - SUMMARY
- 20121026 - More events
- 20120905T173000Z - events over events
- 20120929T160000Z - so much to do
- 20140629 - calendar entry

As you can see, there is an event 2014/07/04 but the next event ist 2012/10/26

Do the owner of the calendar has to do any settings in his/her calendar or why do i get them unordered ?

If know, if there isn't any solution, i need to read in every event into an array, and the filter them for $today < $eventdatum.... but i don't want so much work :)

I hope you can help me, greetings from germany, 
Timo﻿

Comment: Any reason you want to use the ICS file rather than the normal Google calendar API?

Comment: well not really, but i think its a little bit overweight for such an little application :)
at least, the url of the ics is hardcoded into the php file, for easiness

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just fetching the relevant URL will fetch the calendar items in an Atom format (or as JSON, depending on which version you use) instead of ICS... why is that "overweight"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for google to put things in order. You should read in the data and order it yourself.

In php, you can use [sabre/vobject](https://github.com/fruux/sabre-vobject) to do this. You can very easily read the data in and let the library return the dates for you.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.